# How do I arrive at the multiplication function in lambda calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus, church-numerals

I'm familiar with how Church numerals are defined in the lambda calculus, i.e. as functions that take two arguments and apply the first argument $n$ times to the second.

Then I have the successor and addition functions, both of which I managed to derive and understand:

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{succ} &:= \lambda nsz.s (n s z) \\
(+) &:= \lambda nm.n\ succ\ m \\
\end{align} $$

But multiplication is where I'm stuck.

I understand that we can define a multiplication function $(*)$ by adding the number $m$ to $0$ exactly $n$ times. After all, $3 \times 2$ is simply $2 + 2 + 2 + 0$.

So that could mean that $(*)$ looks like this:

$$(*) := \lambda nm.n\ ((+)\ m)\ 0$$

This appears to be a somewhat intuitive definition of a lambda calculus multiplication function to me, and if I try it out with $2$ and $3$, after some messy reductions, the result seems correct and $(*)\,2\,3 \rightarrow 6$.

But then elsewhere I found this definition for multiplication:

$$\mathrm{mult} := \lambda xya.x (y a)$$

Now I don't see how you arrive at this function $\mathrm{mult}$. My definition $(*)$, which takes two arguments, seems intuitive enough to me. But his here, which takes two arguments, one for the $x$ and $y$ respectively, which are the numbers to be multiplied, and then a third one $a$, just seems impenetrable to me—and I cannot figure out why it works, or how you would derive it.

Can somebody help me understand the reasoning and derivation of this $\mathrm{mult}$ function?

Comment: If you left only the essence of your question, it would be much much better. I think you don't really need steps 1 - 3 and that computation in step 4.

Comment: Apologies. This was my very first question here, and I may indeed have been too verbose. I edited my initial question and shortened it significantly to focus on the essence of my problem.

Comment: I also find your own $(*)$ easier to understand. The same approach also works for exponentiation $exp =\lambda n m.\ n((*) m)$. (By the way, exponentiation can also be done with $\lambda ab.\ ba$ which is even more cryptic than $mult$ is. It can be "decrypted" in similar ways, though.)

Comment: You may want to check the Mikrokosmos interpreter for doing this complex reductions: https://mroman42.github.io/mikrokosmos/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know that $(\bar{n}\ s)$ corresponds to $s^{(n)}$, i.e. function $s$ applied $n$ times to its argument. You want to obtain a function that iterates some function $s$ exactly $n \cdot m$ times. From the above observations and some simple rules for the composition of functions we can immediately derive the body of $\textsf{mult}$:

$$s ^ {(n \cdot m)} =
\left( s ^ {(m)} \right) ^ {(n)} = 
\bar{n} \left(s ^ {(m)} \right) = 
\bar{n}\ (\bar{m}\ s) 
$$

Hence

$$ \textsf{mult}\ :=\ \overbrace{\lambda n m.}^\text{  parameters}\underbrace{(\lambda sz.n\ (m\ s) z)}_{\text{Church numeral}}$$

or, if we $\eta$-contract, we get

$$ \textsf{mult}\ :=\ \lambda nms.n\ (m\ s)$$

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the term "η-contract", could you elaborate on that?

I seem to be missing how you get from $\lambda nm.(\lambda sz.n\ (m\ s)z)$ to $\lambda nms.n\ (m\ s)$.

Comment: Roughly, $f$ and $(\lambda x. f x)$ behave the same. You can find more on this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#η-conversion).